# When I click on a button focus goes to text area

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to CSS and HTML and I'm facing a very strange issue here, I have text area in my html as below.

```
<div class="ContentBox BPMSectionBody LastContentBox noHeader" id="div_3_1_1_2_11_1_1_1_1_1_1_10_1" data-view-managed="false">

  <div class="Text_Area fullWidthTextArea CoachView CoachView_hidden CoachView_show" id="div_3_1_1_2_11_1_1_1_1_1_1_10_1_1" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Text_Area8" data-config="config99" data-bindingtype="String" data-binding="local.userAction.comments"
  data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_7a0c03cc_ccef_4582_a1bc_7ccc8e9be488.Text_Area">

    <div class="textLabel">
      <label class="text controlLabel" id="div_3_1_1_2_11_1_1_1_1_1_1_10_1_1_label">Enter Cancellation Comments</label>
      <div class="coachValidationDiv">
        <img class="coachValidationImg smallImg CoachView_hidden" role="alert" alt="Error" src="/teamworks/webasset/2064.7a0c03cc-ccef-4582-a1bc-7ccc8e9be488/W/Error_icon_24x24.png">
        <span class="coachValidationText" style="visibility: hidden;">!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea tabindex="0" class="dijitTextBox dijitTextArea dijitExpandingTextArea BPMTextAreaFont" id="dijit_form_Textarea_16" aria-labelledby="div_3_1_1_2_11_1_1_1_1_1_1_10_1_1_label" style="-ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden; box-sizing: border-box;"
    rows="1" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode,containerNode,textbox" widgetId="dijit_form_Textarea_16" autocomplete="off" value=""></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a button as below :

```
<div class="Button pageFlowButton CoachView CoachView_show" id="div_3_1_1_2_12_1_2" data-eventid="boundaryEvent_17" data-viewid="Button10" data-config="config83" data-bindingtype="" data-binding="" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_7a0c03cc_ccef_4582_a1bc_7ccc8e9be488.Button">
  <button class="BPMButton BPMButtonBorder" type="button">Continue With Selected Action</button>
</div>
```

when I start typing in textarea and having my cursor still in the textarea and i click on button for the first time instead of action being taken, text area gets focused.
When I click button second time it works fine.

Can any body please help,what can be the possible reason here??

Comment: Are the button and the textarea in the same form?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using jQuery, I guess you should use:

```
$('.Text_Area').click(function(noFocus){
  noFocus.preventDefault();
});
```